# Magento file changes not taking effect and flushing cache

Tags: php, caching, magento

I'm copying a Magento Enterprise 1.11.2.0 core file called Preview.php into the local folder with same directory structure to override this particular file because it is not functioning properly. More specifically, it is not allowing the transactional emails to be previewed. I made changes for a fix in the .php file that goes in the local folder, but Magento doesn't seem to think there are any changes. I even tried modifying the core file itself to additional garbage strings appended to the returned variable, but that didn't register either.

Now, as I understand it, I need to flush the cache, but I don't think I'm doing this properly for these changes to take effect. In the Cache Management section, I've tried "Flush Magento Cache," but I have not tried "Flush Cache Storage" because I was told not to touch that from the person who set up our installation. What are the differences? Could flushing the cache storage make the overriding preview.php kick into action?

ADD:
The directory structure is correct. As I mentioned, some files (while others take effect just fine) changes is not recognized by Magento installation for some reason.. One of our guys thinks maybe it's one of the extensions we're using that is overriding some portions, but I really don't see anything that's overriding the core app files or images in the skin folder.

For example, if I delete "logo_email.gif" in the theme folder we're using, it should fall back to the default Magento logo image. Instead, the Magento instanace thinks the file is still there and even loads it! I'm forced to create our own logo file called logo_email.png and load this file in the email templates, because deleting or overwriting this file doesn't work.

I've submitted a support ticket to Magento.. I will update if I make any progress.

Comment: Is your directory structure correct?

Comment: Have the same problem. Copied new logo_email.gif but old one is still cached. Cleared cache couple of times to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the culprit was the Magento compilation feature, under System -> Tools. Disabling this allows for the code changes to take effect!

Comment: Just recompile when changes happen to PHP files. I do not like the habit of disabling.